# How to shuffle characters within a string in C

Tags: c, string, random, shuffle

I am creating a program and part of it needs to take a word, and jumble the letters.
I know that there is officially no string data type within C, so technically the characters in the word are already in array? They just need sorting. (That is my understanding anyway).
I also know that C isn't very good for actual random numbers, I normally use the time as the seed, not sure if this would affect shuffling the letters.

**For instance:**

The word *Hello* 
Split into Characters *H/E/L/L/O* 
Shuffled *E/L/O/H/L* 
New word *Elohl*

Comment: so, basically what's your question?

Comment: @SouravGhosh 'How to shuffle characters within a string in C?'

Comment: In that case, I would like to ask you to please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

Comment: please provide what you have coded so far - we are here to help you with problems, not to do your homework

Comment: @mfro I'm not after someone to do it, I just need pointing in the right direction, what the best way to do this is, I have no clue where to start, as I know some languages have a built in command to do this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495298/shuffle-a-string-input-by-user

Comment: There are *lots* of questions/answers on SO about shuffling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> technically the characters in the word are already in array?

You can treat them like a null-terminated array of characters. Apply your favorite shuffle algorithm to the portion of the string between 0, inclusive, and `strlen(str)`, exclusive to produce a shuffled string.

The only catch here is that not all strings can be shuffled in place. Specifically, strings representing string literals are not writable. Trying to change them would lead to undefined behavior.

For example, if you do

```
char *word = "hello";
shuffle(word);
```

and try to modify `word`'s characters inside `shuffle`, you would get undefined behavior. You need to copy the content into a writable array before you can shuffle the content - for example, like this:

```
char word[] = "hello";
shuffle(word);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b){
        return *(const char *)a - *(const char *)b;
    }

    char arr[] = "dbaurjvgeofx";

    printf("Unsorted: %s\n", arr);
    qsort(arr, strlen(arr), 1, compare);
    printf("Sorted: %s\n", arr);
```